# Pandas' pivot_table: Adding % and running % as aggfunc

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to create a pivot table that has 3 measures on the same value being aggregated:

1. np.sum
2. % of total
3. running % of total (the sum of all % values up to and including that row)

It's pretty easy to do that in two stages - standard pivot_table with np.sum and afterwards add two more columns to the pt. What I'm interested is to know if you can do it during the creation of the pivot table, by passing the right aggfuncs.

Here's what I've done (I'll be using the build in sample data sets seaborn comes with):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

# Two stage approach:
# 1 - Pivot:
pt = pd.pivot_table(tips, index = ['day'], values = ['tip'], aggfunc=np.sum)

# 2 - add new columns
tot_tips = pt['tip'].sum()
pt['% of tot tips'] = pt['tip']/tot_tips               # percent of total
pt['Agg % of tot tips'] = pt['% of tot tips'].cumsum() # running %
```

This delivers just fine, but I wonder if there's a shorter approach, working directly with the aggfuncs.

Here's the closest I got:

```
tot_tips = pt['tip'].sum()  # need to define this one

pt2 = pd.pivot_table(tips, index = ['day'], values = ['tip'], 
aggfunc=[np.sum, (lambda x: sum(x/tot_tips))])
```

This is a little better (yields the sum and % columns) but:

- No running %
- I couldn't get around having to define what the column total ahead of time.
- Column headers... how can I control the name the % column gets?

Would really appreciate help achieving the above, and also any suggestions how to improve the syntax above would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't the first approach be better in terms of computation cost? The mathematical operations should be vectorized in the first case, and run row by row in the second. I would run them past `%timeit` before investing time in making the code more compact.

Comment: Fair point but - for small data sets it would be negligible and I'd personally find an aggfunc solution more elegant. Also, I need to have an alternative solution so I could compare how long it took to compute :)

Comment: Just compare the time taken to compute the sum, and the percent. Don't include cumulative percentage in the comparison. Aggfunc will also make the code difficult to read, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, but even if just for small sets or the learning value, I'd still love to know if the above can be done with aggfuncs. Thanks for your insights!